# Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> string $method ]] in class RoachPHP\Http\Request #8

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping, laravel-8

Hello guys I'm trying to use this package: roach-PHP/Laravel
I face this error above
I created a new issue on the GitHub package waiting for... On the other side if any on can help resolve this issue please share your help we will be most thankful

````
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use RoachPHP\Http\Response;
use RoachPHP\Spider\BasicSpider;

class RoachDocsSpider extends BasicSpider
{
    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    public array $startUrls = [
        'https://roach-php.dev/docs/spiders'
    ];
 
    public function parse(Response $response): \Generator
    {
        $title = $response->filter('h1')->text();

        $subtitle = $response
            ->filter('main > div:nth-child(2) p:first-of-type')
            ->text();

        yield $this->item([
            'title' => $title,
            'subtitle' => $subtitle,
        ]);
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

you need to call it like this:

```
use RoachPHP\Roach;

Roach::startSpider(RoachDocsSpider ::class);
```

try to put a dd() before yield

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use RoachPHP\Http\Response;
use RoachPHP\Spider\BasicSpider;

class RoachDocsSpider extends BasicSpider
{
    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    public array $startUrls = [
        'https://roach-php.dev/docs/spiders'
    ];
 
    public function parse(Response $response): \Generator
    {
        $title = $response->filter('h1')->text();

        $subtitle = $response
            ->filter('main > div:nth-child(2) p:first-of-type')
            ->text();

dd($title,$subtitle);

        yield $this->item([
            'title' => $title,
            'subtitle' => $subtitle,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Salanta in advance , i tried your solution but the issue still the same as well as i also open this issue on the official repository,
https://github.com/roach-php/laravel/issues/8
if roach-php works with you please share you experience here , all helps are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: **Command**

Make sure you publish the config file

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider='RoachPHP\Laravel\RoachServiceProvider'
```

Step 2: **Command**

use the Roach namespace App/Spider, Roach PhP will create a App/Http/Spider folder and spider with this command:

```
php artisan roach:spider RoachDocsSpider
```

Step 3: **Spider**
Copy the spider to your spiter in App/http/Spider/RoachDocsSpider

```
<?php

namespace App\Spiders;

use RoachPHP\Http\Response;
use RoachPHP\Spider\BasicSpider;

class RoachDocsSpider extends BasicSpider
{
    public array $startUrls = [
        'https://roach-php.dev/docs/spiders'
    ];

    public array $downloaderMiddleware = [
        RequestDeduplicationMiddleware::class,
    ];

    public array $spiderMiddleware = [
        //
    ];

    public array $itemProcessors = [
        //
    ];

    public array $extensions = [
        LoggerExtension::class,
        StatsCollectorExtension::class,
    ];

    public int $concurrency = 2;

    public int $requestDelay = 1;

    /**
     * @return Generator<ParseResult>
     */
    public function parse(Response $response): Generator
    {
        $title = $response->filter('h1')->text();

        $subtitle = $response
            ->filter('main > div:nth-child(2) p:first-of-type')
            ->text();

        dd($title,$subtitle);

        yield $this->item([
            'title' => $title,
            'subtitle' => $subtitle,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Step 4: **Controller**

Test it in you controller by calling

```
use RoachPHP\Roach;

public function index(){

   Roach::startSpider(RoachDocsSpider::class);

 return view('...');
}
```

Comment: didn't yet work brother seems like a string of errors one disappear and two brings.
many thank you for your efforts brother